# подключиться к серверу через ssh

Tags: windows, ssh

Есть сервер, доступ к файлам которого осуществляю через filezilla. Есть ли какой либо способ просматривать все файлы сервера прямо через проводник windows? чтобы зашел в Мой компьютер и там увидел диск с этим сервером сразу, не вводя логинов и паролей всяких. знаю что на mac такое 100% возможно, хотя инструкцию посеял, вопрос можно ли это сделать на windows и если да, то как?

Comment: Погуглите про `ssh` ключи, `putty`, и `mc`. Возможно это оно. :)

Comment: я итак пользуюсь ssh ключами и putty =) это ваще не оно))

Comment: Пример хорошего вопроса с плохой формулировкой

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, подключить как сетевой диск используя стандартный функционал.
В Проводнике - подключить сетевой диск, в диалоговом окне - Подключение к сайту, на котором можно хранить файлы - указываем адрес ftp(sftp) сервера ftp://example.com, имя пользователя, при подключении указываем пароль и ставим галку сохранить. Работает, но не всегда хорошо.
Можно найти стороннее ПО, которое работает более стабильно и функционально. Тут подскажет гугл.